# How to get values from html tag within Angular interpolation?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I have an Angular app with the following markup:

```html
<p>{{item.content}}</p>
```

The displayed content looks something like this:

```html
<p>You can find the content here <a href='javascript:;' ZID='01' TID='11' EID='21' type='link'>TEST</a> and don't forget to visit other sites.</p>
```

In other words, the result of the Angular interpolation is always a string with words mixed with an `<a>` tag with various attributes.

Since this is an Angular (and Cordova, but that's irrelevant in this context) app, what I really need to do is use `routerLink` like this:

```html
<p [routerLink]="['/01/11/21']">You can find the content here <a href='javascript:;' ZID='01' TID='11' EID='21' type='link'>TEST</a> and don't forget to visit other sites.</p>
```

The question is: how can I obtain the values from the `ZID`, `TID`, and `EID` attributes from the Angular interpolation `{{item.content}}` and plug them into `routerLink`?

Answer (score 1):

you can get value by `getAttribute`

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("ZID");
```

Answer (score 0):

Shailesh has posted right answer, here I have just wrap it to one of the lifecycle of Angular Page `ngAfterViewInit` and instead of get from `document` I have search in current component by `ElementRef`. Now you have to decide how many `a` tag in your page and how you fetch required attribute from it, it all about logic now.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

constructor(public el: ElementRef) {
}

ngAfterViewInit(){
   var x = this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].getAttribute("ZID"); 
   console.log(x);
}
```

You can also get other attributes as above and combine them in one variable and assign that variable to `[routerLink]`.